# PHP: How to get the min and max of a Multidimensional Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional array.

```
$dog_treats=array(
    array(
        'Rupert' = array(
        'Breed' => 'German Shepherd',
        'treats' = array(
            0 => 3,
            1 => 2,
            2 => 6
        ),
     ),
        'Zeus' = array(
        'Breed' => 'Golden Retreiver',
        'treats' = array(
             0 => 5,
             1 => 4,
             2 => 1,
             3 => 2
        ),
     ),
   ),
);
```

The syntax is a bit off but that's how it looks like. The code that creates it is:

```
$dog_treats['Rupert']['Breed'] = 'German Shepherd';
$dog_treats['Rupert']['treats'][0] = 3;
$dog_treats['Rupert']['treats'][1] = 2;
$dog_treats['Rupert']['treats'][2] = 6;

$dog_treats['Zeus']['Breed'] = 'Golden Retreiver';
$dog_treats['Zeus']['treats'][0] = 5;
$dog_treats['Zeus']['treats'][1] = 4;
$dog_treats['Zeus']['treats'][2] = 1;
$dog_treats['Zeus']['treats'][3] = 2;
```

For each dog I want to get the maximum and minimum number of treats they ate that day. How do I do this? Thanks

Rupert max = 6 min = 2

Zeus max = 5 min = 1

Comment: there is a `min()` and a `max()` function in php

Comment: I know that but it's tricky for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: it would of been nice to see your attempt (we like that around here) :-) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically:

```
foreach ($dog_treats as $k=>$v){
  echo $k.'<br>';
  echo "max: ". max($dog_treats[$k]['treats']).'<br>';
  echo "min: ". min($dog_treats[$k]['treats']).'<br>';
}
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/BGeMGx

**OR**

```
foreach ($dog_treats as $k=>$v){
  echo $k.'<br>';
  echo "max: ". max($v['treats']).'<br>';
  echo "min: ". min($v['treats']).'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Why not just `$v['treats']`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic why not indeed -functionally the same and unlikely to have a speed issue. php, a dozen ways to do anything

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the min/max treats in the array you could use array_walk and apply those values:

```
array_walk($dogs, function(&$dog) {
    $dog['min'] = min($dog['treats']);
    $dog['max'] = max($dog['treats']);
});
```

If you just want to the print the min/max, you could use a foreach loop and simply echo:

```
echo 'min: ' . min($dog['treats']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the array at once then you can use the following code:

```
$dog_treats = array(
    array(
        'Rupert' => array(
            'Breed' => 'German Shepherd',
            'treats' => array(
                0 => 3,
                1 => 2,
                2 => 6
            ),
         ),
        'Zeus' => array(
            'Breed' => 'Golden Retreiver',
            'treats' => array(
                 0 => 5,
                 1 => 4,
                 2 => 1,
                 3 => 2
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

foreach($dog_treats as $key) {
    foreach($key as $dog => $value) {
        echo 'Dog: '.$dog.', Max: '.max($value['treats']).', Min: '.min($value['treats']).'<br />';
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Dog: Rupert, Max: 6, Min: 2
Dog: Zeus, Max: 5, Min: 1
```

Comment: you don't really need 2 loops

Comment: Hm, why not? Based on the $dog_treats array i used it's an array holding one or many arrays holding one or many dogs

Comment: look at my answer, 1 loop

Comment: I checked it. It doesn't work for the multidimensional array.

Comment: Yes, that code works providing the array in that format. But it doesn't work if you define $dog_treats array as i defined it in my answer (also questioner's array). I 've double checked it.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis you are using the array from the top part of the question. Unfortunately, "the code that creates it" does not actually create that array. (It looks like there is an extra array in there, probably a typo.)

Comment: Yes. This is because it's a different array. It has one more level. This is what i' am trying to say.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that there are actually two slightly different arrays in the question. Your code works on the first one, and Dagon's works on the second one.

Comment: well then your simply answering a different question than the OP is actually asking

Comment: No, we just solved two different problems in one question!

Comment: well using your array you just loop `$dog_treats[0]` still only one loop required ;-)

Comment: Yes, i tried this but it wouldn't be a general solution because the outer array could hold more arrays and not only one.